# Difference of regex anchors between .NET and javascript

Tags: javascript, .net, regex

On my frontend, I have a regex in javascript to detect if the email was correct.

```
^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$
```

Current backend Regex validation, on .NET is:

```
Regex.IsMatch(email, @"\A(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)\Z", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

I **want to replace the .NET regex by the javascript one** But I'm really "lost" in the begin/end characters.

**In the .NET regex, have `\A` and `\Z` the same utility than `^` and `$` in my javascript one?**

I tried to replace my .NET regex as follows, but it doesn't detect valid string even if in Javascript it was correct:

```
Regex.IsMatch(email, @"\A(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))\Z", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: No duplicate about Email Validation: my question is not about the correct regex to use, but about the begind/end symbol difference between Javascript and C#

Comment: Have you seen the [MSDN reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx)? And [Anchors in Regular Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5181w5w(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thanks Jasen for reference. I tried to keep A and Z but it doesn't validate the string correctly.

Comment: Well, now you have a second question. You should create a new post with example data.

Comment: The answer given is wrong, why did you accept it? Vladu just pasted the description of the anchors from the .NET reference, in JS, the `\A` and `\Z` are not supported and `$` does not behave the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> ^ -   The match must occur at the beginning of the string or line. 
> $ -   The match must occur at the end of the string or line, or before \n at the end of the string or line.
> \A -  The match must occur at the beginning of the string only (no multiline support).
> \Z -  The match must occur at the end of the string, or before \n at the end of the string.
> ```

Comment: So the difference is to support or not multiline?

Comment: I edited the question: i tried to keep the A and Z anchors but it doesn't validate the string as it is done in javascript